# Google Sheets Email Script Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm new to creating scripts, but I've been trying to write a script to send a message to 500+ emails that I have in a Google Sheet. I copied a code I found on a Google Tutorial and then tried to adjust it to the appropriate columns in my Sheet and to include a formatted email message with links. Everything worked fine until I added my custom message, now I get the error message "Missing ) after argument list. (line 28, file "Code")." Line 28 is "MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);"

I'm new to this, so its probably a simple mistake. I've included the full script below. I appreciate any help.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 523;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:F523
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 523)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var firstName = row[1];
    var emailAddress = row[5];  // Sixth column
    var message = <p>"Hi " + firstName + ",/n Are you looking for new ways to integrate technology into your lessons? Heartland AEA is offering a FREE professional development opportunity focused on integrating technology into Social Studies instruction. As part of our Technology Integration and Collaboration (TIC) series, this session will provide a free opportunity for educators from throughout Heartland's area to learn from exemplary teachers while collaborating with others who are passionate about education, technology, and social studies. We have a great lineup of presenters and would love to have as many educators as possible in attendance. If you are unable to attend in person, please consider participating through the livestream via Zoom.</p> +
<p>Whether you plan to attend in person or via Zoom, please '<a href=\"' + 'https://prodev.aeapdonline.org/4DCGI/TE099892111701INV&*' + '>register</a> in advance. More information about this and other upcoming TIC sessions can be found on the '<a href=\"' + 'https://sites.google.com/a/heartlandaea.org/heartland-tic/home' + '>TIC website</a>.</p> +
<p>Topic: 6-12 Social Studies: Quality Instruction Using Technology</p> +
<p>Date: January 12, 2017 </p> +
<p>Time: 8:30am - 11:30am   </p> +
<p>Location: Johnston AEA</p> +
<p>To Register: '<a href=\"' + 'https://prodev.aeapdonline.org/4DCGI/TE099892111701INV&*' + '>Click Here</a>. It is FREE!</p> +
<p>Zoom Link: '<a href=\"' + 'https://heartlandaea.zoom.us/j/804914526' + '>https://heartlandaea.zoom.us/j/804914526</a> </p> +
<p>If you are unable to attend virtually or in person, we will post videos of each presentation to '<a href=\"' + 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRAy7hvczWAXWKj4b6buttfLsGWLKGP8s' + '>Heartland’s YouTube Channel</a> a few days after this session. </p> +
<p>Please pass this information on to all Social Studies teachers in your district or others in your building that might be interested in attending."</p>;   

var emailSent = row[7];     // Seventh column
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
  var subject = "Technology in Social Studies PD";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things that might help.

Since you are using html, use this to send email:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
```

Is message formatted correctly, there seems to be "" missing in places.  try this:

```
var message = "<p>Hi " + firstName + ",/n Are you looking for new ways to integrate technology into your lessons?"
+ "Heartland AEA is offering a FREE professional development opportunity focused on integrating technology into Social Studies instruction. As part of our Technology Integration and Collaboration (TIC) series, this session will provide a free opportunity for educators from throughout Heartland's area to learn from exemplary teachers while collaborating with others who are passionate about education, technology, and social studies. We have a great lineup of presenters and would love to have as many educators as possible in attendance. If you are unable to attend in person, please consider participating through the livestream via Zoom.</p>"
+ "<p>Whether you plan to attend in person or via Zoom, please '<a href=\"' + 'https://prodev.aeapdonline.org/4DCGI/TE099892111701INV&*' + '>register</a> in advance. More information about this and other upcoming TIC sessions can be found on the '<a href=\"' + 'https://sites.google.com/a/heartlandaea.org/heartland-tic/home' + '>TIC website</a>.</p>"
+ "<p>Topic: 6-12 Social Studies: Quality Instruction Using Technology</p>" 
+ "<p>Date: January 12, 2017 </p>" 
+ "<p>Time: 8:30am - 11:30am   </p>" 
+ "<p>Location: Johnston AEA</p>"
+ "<p>To Register: '<a href=\"' + 'https://prodev.aeapdonline.org/4DCGI/TE099892111701INV&*' + '>Click Here</a>. It is FREE!</p>"
+ "<p>Zoom Link: '<a href=\"' + 'https://heartlandaea.zoom.us/j/804914526' + '>https://heartlandaea.zoom.us/j/804914526</a> </p>"
+ "<p>If you are unable to attend virtually or in person, we will post videos of each presentation to '<a href=\"' + 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRAy7hvczWAXWKj4b6buttfLsGWLKGP8s' + '>Heartland’s YouTube Channel</a> a few days after this session. </p>"
+ "<p>Please pass this information on to all Social Studies teachers in your district or others in your building that might be interested in attending.</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to play around a little more to get the links to work in the message, but I got it.